# Updating multi-model form from Angular to Sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, sinatra

I'm currently having an issue with updating a form in Angular and pushing the update through to Sinatra.

It is supposed to:

- When clicked, the form to edit the current item is shown (current data for each field is displayed from the item scope).
- When submitted, it is attempting to update to a different scope (updateinfo). I am not sure but do I need a way of using multiscope or one scope to allow it to update?
- At present the script sends the correct downloadID parameter, but the JSON from the scope submitted is as I believe, incorrect.
- Also, I'm not sure whether the Sinatra app.rb syntax is correct, for someone new to these frameworks, it has been hard to find useful documentation online.

If anybody could help it would be very much appreciated.

downloads.html

```
<div ng-show="showEdit">
                <form ng-submit="updateinfo(item.downloadID); showDetails = ! showDetails;">
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="title">Title</label><input type="text"
                                                                                     ng-model="item.title"
                                                                                     value="{{item.title}}"/></div>
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="caption">Download caption</label><input type="text"
                                                                                                  ng-model="item.caption"
                                                                                                  value="{{item.caption}}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="dlLink">Download link</label><input type="url"
                                                                                              ng-model="item.dlLink"
                                                                                              value="{{item.dlLink}}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="imgSrc">Image source</label><input type="url"
                                                                                             ng-model="item.imgSrc"
                                                                                             value="{{item.imgSrc}}"/>
                    </div>


                    <!-- download live input types need to be parsed as integers to avoid 500 internal server error   -->
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="imgSrc">
                        <label name="dlLive">Download live</label><input type="radio" ng-model="download.dl_live"
                                                                         value="1"/>
                        <label name="dlLive">Not live</label><input type="radio" ng-model="download.dl_live"
                                                                    value="0"/></div>
                    <div class="input-group"><label name="imgSrc"><input type="submit"/></div>
                </form>
```

controllers.js

```
$scope.loadData = function () {
    $http.get('/view1/downloadData').success(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
};
$scope.loadData();
$scope.updateinfo = function(downloadID) {
    id = downloadID
    var result = $scope.items.filter(function( items ) {
        return items.downloadID == id;
    });
    console.log(result);
    updatedata = $scope.items
    $http({
        method : 'PUT',
        url :  '/view1/downloadedit/:downloadID',
        data : result
    });

    };
```

app.rb

```
#edit download
put '/view1/downloadedit' do
puts 'angular connection working'
ng_params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
puts ng_params
@download = Download.update(ng_params)
end
```

Comment: All the `ng-model` in form point to object `item` but don't see you reference that to send to server. `data : $scope.updateinfo` ..same name as function?

Comment: Inspect your AJAX requests in browser console. Can see exactly what is sent

Comment: @charlietfl yes the ng-model is item, so I think I should be sending that to the server.. yes that has duplicated the function name so must be incorrect?

Comment: exactly... not sure if you need to add the download ID but seem on right track

Comment: changing the scope now outputs the correct json, it's now just getting a 500 error from sinatra

Comment: I work in php... but have problems sometimes sending the `$$hashKey` property that angular adds to every object it touches in all scopes. Try `delete item['$$hashKey'];` before sending it

Comment: okk, I think it's the connection between the url of angular's method and sinatra's route is not matching up and causing the 500? Is that to do with the $$hashKey property?

Comment: no. I think `$$` is illegal prefix for form params though. 500 is definitely a server problem

Comment: Yeah I think it's Angular's URL request causing it, although I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for both Angular and Sinatra

Comment: i've updated the code so that sinatra is receiving the correct JSON from ng_params, but the only problem is now it's not updating the record in the database, I'm still wondering if this is a routing issue.

Comment: no knowledge of sinatra routng here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong scope was attempting to be used. Once the scope was corrected to items, the correct JSON was being routed:

```
$scope.updateinfo = function(downloadID) {
id = downloadID
var result = $scope.items.filter(function( items ) {
    return items.downloadID == id;
});
console.log(result);
updatedata = $scope.items
$http({
    method : 'PUT',
    url :  '/view1/downloadedit/:downloadID',
    data : result
});
```